# assembly code find matching string in array

Tags: assembly, mips

a program that examines the occurrence of a certain pattern in a string: End on line 18 represents the end of the program.
• The input is given to the array Pat (base address $ s0) of type char and Str (base address $ s1) respectively. A null character (\ 0, ASCII code 0) is placed at the end of both strings. 
• Every time the pattern Pat appears in the string Str, the first position is stored in the integer array AP (base address $ s2), and the total number of appearances is output to the register $ s3. In the case of PAT="ABC", Str ="ABCAABCBABC", AP [0] = 0, AP1 = 4, AP [2] = 8, and $ s3 = 3 are output.

I need to make code according this specification, this is my attempt

```
Main:
add $s3, $zero, $zero
add $t4, $zero, $zero

LoopO: add $t0, $s0, $zero
add $t1,$s1,$t4

LoopI: lb $t2, 0($t0)
beq $t2, $zero, Find
lb $t3,0($t1)
beq $t3,$zero,Fin
bne $t2,$t3,Next
addi $t0,$t0,1
addi $t1,$t1,1
j LoopI

Find:
sw $t4,0($s2)
addi $s2,$s2,4
addi $s3,$s3,1

Next :
addi $t4,$t4,$t1
j Loop0

Fin:End
```

but when there is no match in PAT and STR array, for example Pat="ABC"  and Str="BAC" , the first character is not same, in first iteration in Loop1 it'll jump to Next then, add $ t1 to register $ t4, but $t1 is 0 and t4 is 0 too, so when it goes to Loop0 to reset it not advance to next char in array,
if i change to addi $t4,$t4,1 , it also not quite right, since i want $t4 to be register that point to what character in str array

any suggestions?

Comment: How does this relate to C? What processor is this for?

Comment: @vandench this related to c, because usually we translate c to assembly or assembly to mips for better understanding(?)

Comment: First create your algorithm using pseudocode, a high level language or a flowchart. When you are satisfied that it works correctly, code it in asm. That said, based on what I could understand from your logic it seems correct, you want to increment the haystack position by one so `addi $t4,$t4,1`. Do you have an actual problem?

Comment: @Jester the problem is, there is im not sure about the register $t4 and $s1 , because it not produce right result